# The center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

prove that for any group $G$, $Z(G)=\bigcap_{x\in G} C_{G}(\{x\})$ . In addition, show that if $H\subset G$ , then $C_{G}(H)=\bigcap_{x\in H} C_{G}(\{x\})$

$Z(G)$ is the center of a group and 
$C_{G}(\{x\})$ are the centralizers.

Like I know how to prove the first part, but I do not know how to prove the second part. Would someone be willing to help me out.

Comment: show the additional statement by proving LHS $\subset$ RHS and RHS $\subset$ LHS.

Comment: If you use the technique you used for the center $Z(G)$, what goes wrong trying to apply it to the centralizer $C_G(H)$?

Answer (score 2):

$C_G (H) =$ {$g \in G \;|\; hg = gh$ for all $ h \in H$}

First show that $C_G(H) \subset \bigcap_{x\in H} C_{G}(\{x\})$

So if $y \in C_G(H)$, then $y \in C_G(h)$ for all $h \in H$ which is the same as saying $y \in \bigcap_{x\in H} C_{G}(\{x\})$

Then you have to show $C_G(H) \supset \bigcap_{x\in H} C_{G}(\{x\})$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g \in \bigcap\limits_{x \in H} C_G(x)$.

Then $g$ commutes with every $x \in H$, so $g \in C_G(H)$.

Can you continue?

Comment: I don't understand your comment-we are concerned with the subset $H$.

Comment: I am really sorry I did not get it yet

Comment: What does it mean if $g \in C_G(H)$?

Comment: @philip it means that $g\in C_{G}(h)$ for all $h\in H$ , Thus $x\in \bigcap_{x\in H} C_{G}(\{x\})$ ??

Comment: Um that notation is inconsistent. If $g \in C_G(h)$ for some h, then gh=hg, right? Well if it's true for $h_1$ that $g \in C_G(h_1)$, $h_2$ that $g \in C_G(h_2)$... then g is in the intersection of all of them

Comment: Oh wait no I made a notation error. Fixed